# Hibernate Envers audit oneToMany side too, even if it has no changes

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Have two entities `Instrument` and `Definition`.

When `instrumentCode` changed Envers create audited record only for `Instrument`.

I want that when `instrumentCode` changed Envers create audited records for both `Instrument` and `Definition` entities. How it is possible to do, and is it possible?

I've played with @AuditedJoinTable, @AuditedMappedBy but without luck.

```
@Audited
@Getter
@Entity
public class Instrument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "instrument_code")
    protected String instrumentCode;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Definition.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "definition_id", nullable = false)
    private Definition definition;
}
//-----
@Audited
@Getter
@Entity
public class Definition {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "definition",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            targetEntity = Instrument.class)
    private Set<Instrument> instruments = Sets.newHashSet();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any out of the box available configurations for that already available at this moment (although it seems that something similar [is being developed](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11857)).

Probably you could merge the revisions of the two together manually via [audit queries](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/query/AuditQuery.html) when fetching history to keep the audit records in the database fully normalized.

Or you could introduce a dummy column in the parent entity and update it whenever children change, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11244196/4754790):

```
@Entity
public class A {
    private Date lastModified;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<B> blist;

    public void touch() {
        lastModified = new Date();
    }
}

public class B {
    @ManyToOne
    private A a; 

    @PreUpdate
    public void ensureParentUpdated() {
        if (a != null) {
            a.touch();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, also thought about dummy field or.. rewrite Envers listeners completly - but this will not be Envers than ).
Thanks for the overall answer